# Select right kernel size for median blur to reduce noise

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, noise-reduction

I am new to image processing. We have a requirement to get circle centers with sub pixel accuracy from an image. I have used median blurring to reduce the noise. A portion of the image is shown below. The steps I followed for getting circle boundaries is given below

1. Reduced the noise with `medianBlur`
2. Applied OTSU thresholding with threshold API
3. Identified circle boundaries with `findContours` method.

I get different results when used different kernel size for `medianBlur`. I selected `medianBlur` to keep edges. I tried kernel size 3, 5 and 7. Now I am confused to use the right kernel size for `medianBlur`.

1. How can I decide the right kernel size?
2. Is there any scientific approach to decide the right kernel size for `medianBlur`?

[image]

Comment: Any blurring is going to change your edges, whether it is a linear filter or a median filter.

Comment: What language do you use? I assumed Python, but it's not clear from your post.

Comment: @Cris - We use C++

Comment: DIPlib is a C++ library, and a lot easier to use than OpenCV, IMO (but I’m biased...). The Python code in my answer translates almost 1:1 to C++. If I have time tonight I can translate it for you. But is the information in the answer useful to you?

Comment: @Cris - The information is useful. If you could provide C++ Code, that would be great.  There is bigger hole in the center of the image.  The requirement is to calculate the distance between the center of the bigger whole and the small holes.

Answer (score 3):

I will give you two suggestions here for how to find the centroids of these disks, you can pick one depending on the level of precision you need.

First of all, using contours is not the best method. Contours depend a lot on which pixels happen to fall within the object on thresholding, noise affects these a lot.

A better method is to find the center of mass (or rather, the first order moments) of the disks. [Read Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment) to learn more about moments in image analysis. One nice thing about moments is that we can use pixel values as weights, increasing precision.

You can compute the moments of a binary shape from its contours, but you cannot use image intensities in this case. OpenCV has a function [`cv::moments`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga556a180f43cab22649c23ada36a8a139) that computes the moments for the whole image, but I don't know of a function that can do this for each object separately. So instead I'll be using [DIPlib](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib) for these computations (I'm an author).

---

#### Regarding the filtering:

Any well-behaved *linear* smoothing should not affect the center of mass of the objects, as long as the objects are far enough from the image edge. Being close to the edge will cause the blur to do something different on the side of the object closest to the edge compared to the other sides, introducing a bias.

Any non-linear smoothing filter has the ability to change the center of mass. Please avoid the median filter.

So, I recommend that you use a Gaussian filter, which is the most well-behaved linear smoothing filter.

---

#### Method 1: use binary shape's moments:

First I'm going to threshold without any form of blurring.

```py
import diplib as dip

a = dip.ImageRead('/Users/cris/Downloads/Ef8ey.png')
a = a(1)  # Use green channel only, simple way to convert to gray scale

_, t = dip.Threshold(a)
b = a<t

m = dip.Label(b)

msr = dip.MeasurementTool.Measure(m, None, ['Center'])
print(msr)
```

This outputs

```
  |                  Center | 
- | ----------------------- | 
  |       dim0 |       dim1 | 
  |       (px) |       (px) | 
- | ---------- | ---------- | 
1 |      18.68 |      9.234 | 
2 |      68.00 |      14.26 | 
3 |      19.49 |      48.22 | 
4 |      59.68 |      52.42 |
```

We can now apply a smoothing to the input image `a` and compute again:

```py
a = dip.Gauss(a,2)

_, t = dip.Threshold(a)
b = a<t
m = dip.Label(b)
msr = dip.MeasurementTool.Measure(m, None, ['Center'])
print(msr)
```

```
  |                  Center | 
- | ----------------------- | 
  |       dim0 |       dim1 | 
  |       (px) |       (px) | 
- | ---------- | ---------- | 
1 |      18.82 |      9.177 | 
2 |      67.74 |      14.27 | 
3 |      19.51 |      47.95 | 
4 |      59.89 |      52.39 |
```

You can see there's some small change in the centroids.

---

#### Method 2: use gray scale moments:

Here we use the error function to apply a pseudo-threshold to the image. What this does is set object pixels to 1 and background pixels to 0, but pixels around the edges retain some intermediate value. Some people refer to this as a "fuzzy thresholding". These two images show the normal ("hard") threshold, and the error function clip ("fuzzy threshold"):

[image: hard threshold]  [image: fuzzy threshold]

By using this fuzzy threshold, we retain more information about the exact (sub-pixel) location of the edges, which we can use when computing the first order moments.

```py
import diplib as dip

a = dip.ImageRead('/Users/cris/Downloads/Ef8ey.png')
a = a(1)  # Use green channel only, simple way to convert to gray scale

_, t = dip.Threshold(a)
c = dip.ContrastStretch(-dip.ErfClip(a, t, 30))

m = dip.Label(a<t)
m = dip.GrowRegions(m, None, -2, 2)

msr = dip.MeasurementTool.Measure(m, c, ['Gravity'])
print(msr)
```

This outputs

```
  |                 Gravity | 
- | ----------------------- | 
  |       dim0 |       dim1 | 
  |       (px) |       (px) | 
- | ---------- | ---------- | 
1 |      18.75 |      9.138 | 
2 |      67.89 |      14.22 | 
3 |      19.50 |      48.02 | 
4 |      59.79 |      52.38 |
```

We can now apply a smoothing to the input image `a` and compute again:

```py
a = dip.Gauss(a,2)

_, t = dip.Threshold(a)
c = dip.ContrastStretch(-dip.ErfClip(a, t, 30))
m = dip.Label(a<t)
m = dip.GrowRegions(m, None, -2, 2)
msr = dip.MeasurementTool.Measure(m, c, ['Gravity'])
print(msr)
```

```
  |                 Gravity | 
- | ----------------------- | 
  |       dim0 |       dim1 | 
  |       (px) |       (px) | 
- | ---------- | ---------- | 
1 |      18.76 |      9.094 | 
2 |      67.87 |      14.19 | 
3 |      19.50 |      48.00 | 
4 |      59.81 |      52.39 |
```

You can see the differences are smaller this time, because the measurement is more precise.

---

In the binary case, the differences in centroids with and without smoothing are:

```
array([[ 0.14768417, -0.05677508],
       [-0.256     ,  0.01668085],
       [ 0.02071882, -0.27547569],
       [ 0.2137167 , -0.03472741]])
```

In the gray-scale case, the differences are:

```
array([[ 0.01277204, -0.04444567],
       [-0.02842993, -0.0276569 ],
       [-0.00023144, -0.01711335],
       [ 0.01776011,  0.01123299]])
```

---

If the centroid measurement is given in µm rather than px, it is because your image file contains pixel size information. The measurement function will use this to give you real-world measurements (the centroid coordinate is w.r.t. the top-left pixel). If you do not desire this, you can reset the image's pixel size:

```py
a.SetPixelSize(1)
```

---

#### The two methods in C++

This is a translation to C++ of the code above, including a display step to double-check that the thresholding produced the right result:

```cpp
#include "diplib.h"
#include "dipviewer.h"
#include "diplib/simple_file_io.h"
#include "diplib/linear.h"       // for dip::Gauss()
#include "diplib/segmentation.h" // for dip::Threshold()
#include "diplib/regions.h"      // for dip::Label()
#include "diplib/measurement.h"
#include "diplib/mapping.h"      // for dip::ContrastStretch() and dip::ErfClip()

int main() {

   auto a = dip::ImageRead("/Users/cris/Downloads/Ef8ey.png");
   a = a[1];  // Use green channel only, simple way to convert to gray scale

   dip::Gauss(a, a, {2});

   dip::Image b;
   double t = dip::Threshold(a, b);
   b = a < t; // Or: dip::Invert(b,b);

   dip::viewer::Show(a);
   dip::viewer::Show(b); // Verify that the segmentation is correct
   dip::viewer::Spin();

   auto m = dip::Label(b);

   dip::MeasurementTool measurementTool;
   auto msr = measurementTool.Measure(m, {}, { "Center"});
   std::cout << msr << '\n';

   auto c = dip::ContrastStretch(-dip::ErfClip(a, t, 30));
   dip::GrowRegions(m, {}, m, -2, 2);

   msr = measurementTool.Measure(m, c, {"Gravity"});
   std::cout << msr << '\n';

   // Iterate through the measurement structure:
   auto it = msr["Gravity"].FirstObject();
   do {
      std::cout << "Centroid coordinates = " << it[0] << ", " << it[1] << '\n';
   } while(++it);
}
```

Comment: @Chris I have tried to execute the first code on the images that I have. The image size is 2K * 2K grey scale.  The image has 286 small circles and one big circle at center with a radius of 170 pixels.  The code it returned 21699 items   |       dim0 |       dim1 | 
      |       (µm) |       (µm) | 
----- | ---------- | ---------- | 
    1 |  2.744e+05 |  2.654e+05 | 
    2 |  2.481e+05 |  1.098e+04 | 
    3 |  2.455e+05 |  1.230e+04 |

Comment: @ Chris . Also msr = dip.MeasurementTool.Measure(m, c, ['Gravity']) . The argument c for the method call is not defined. So I get run time error when I executed the python code

Comment: @Maanu: Sorry, that was a typo, I was re-using the same Python session to run the code as I changed it, I still had a variable `c` in my session. I have amended the code, and also added a C++ translation. If you get 21699 objects analyzed, you will have to do some smoothing. I have added a bit of text to the part of the answer where I talk about smoothing.

Comment: @Maanu: I have also added a note regarding the units of the measurement output.

Comment: @Chris: Thank you very much for updating the C++ Code and updating the response with more details. I tried the python version today. I am getting 288 circles now. One small issue is about the precision. The maximum precision that I get is 1 digit after decimal point.  We need sub pixel accuracy. Should I do anything to set precision?  See the output obtained. Can you help me?             1 |      1038. |      1004. | 
  2 |      1025. |      166.5 | 
  3 |      1094. |      168.7

Comment: @Chris: I have tried Guassian Filter for removing the noise with kernel size 5,5 in open cv. It looks like distance between center of the big circle and small circle become more consistent between different images when we used Gaussian Filter.  I have to run more tests to confirm the behavior. Thanks for your input on Gaussian Filter.

Comment: @Maanu: The MeasurementTool returns double-precision float values. Printing the table might not show all digits, but you can index as `msr['Gravity'][56]`, or you can convert the whole table to a NumPy array: `np.array(msr)`.